# How to read and write from wpa_cupplicant.conf file in android

Tags: java, android, readfile, permission-denied

I am trying to read `wpa_cuoolicant.conf` file but it's give me **error:**

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf:open failed: EACCES (Permission
>   denied)

I can't know if problem happened because i didn't give permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file or problem in java code whatever this is
my `AndroidManifest.xml` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="droidking.checkifisrooted">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and this is my Java Code:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    Runtime.getRuntime()
        .exec("chmod +x /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
    File myFile = new File("/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new 
        BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String aBuffer = "";
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
    }
    textView.setText(aBuffer);
    myReader.close();

    }catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        textView.setText(e.toString());
    }
```

can any one help me to read and write from this file, please.